# Search object by generated string by has_one associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to do a search on the generated model string, which is formed by has_one associations.
Here my models:

Street.rb

```
class Street < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :houses
  validates :street_type, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: {:scope => :street_type, :case_sensitive => false }
  def text
    street_type + " " + name
  end
end
```

House.rb

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :street
  has_many :apartments
  validates :street_id, presence: true
  validates :number, presence: true
  def text
    street.text + ", " + number
  end
end
```

Apartment.rb

```
class Apartment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :house
  has_one :street, through => :house
  has_many :accounts
  validates :house_id, presence: true
  validates :number, presence: true, uniqueness: {:scope => :house_id, :case_sensitive => false}
  def text
    house.text + ", ap. " + number
  end
end
```

Account.rb

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :appartment
  has_one :house, :through => :appartment
  belongs_to :resident
  validates :appartment_id, presence: true
  validates :resident_id, presence: true, uniqueness: {:scope => :appartment_id, :case_sensitive => false}
  def text
    uniq_id + " (" + appartment.text + ")"
  end
end
```

I must search all accounts by matching some adress string. And I have no idea how to do it.

- Example 1st account text "123-1123-122 (Regent street, 51, ap. 3)"
- Example 2nd account text "123-1123-155 (Regent street, 51, ap. 6)"
- Example search text "Regent street, 51"

Can somebody help me understand how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following

```
Account.includes([:appartment => [:house => :street]]).where("CONCAT('accounts.uniq_id', ' (', 'streets.street_type', ' ', 'streets.name', ' ', 'houses.number', ', ap. ', 'houses.number', ')') like '%?%'", your_search_text)
```

Comment: appartments.text is the generated string too. are you sure this code is enough?

Comment: @KirillWarp, I have edited my answer. I have not tested that, just check it, now in this way, you can find the result. you may need to change something in the query.

Answer (score 3):

### Search against joined fields

You are searching against `Account#text`, which is nowhere to be found in DB, unless you store it there (see "Search against full Apartment#text"), which (judging by the code) seems not to be the case.  You can't use return values of your model methods in ActiveRecord queries.  So first you need to parse street type and name, house number and apartment number from your search string.

Assuming you know street type and name, house number and apartment number, you should (minus bugs, I did not actually test that) be able to find the accounts by

```
Account.
  joins(:apartment => { :house => :street }).
  where('apartment.number' => apt_num,
        'apartment.house.number' => house_num,
        'apartment.house.street.name' => street_name,
        'apartment.house.street.street_type' => street_type)
```

Your address information is higly structured.  It may or may not be good.  Without knowing any details I would suggest you to check if less structured or unstructured address information (plain text field) combined with full text search would work for you.

More on AR queries, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

### Search against full Apartment#text

In case you don't want to parse names and numbers from the generated apartment text field, you need to have it stored in db. You can do it by hooking into `before_save` and updating a text field (let it be called `cached_text`) to contain `Apartment#text`.

```
class Apartment < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :update_cached_text
  def update_cached_text
    self.cached_text = text
  end
end
```

Now of course `Apartment#cached_text` will be out of sync if you change house number or street name or type.  To keep it in sync you need to "resave" (see `#touch`) all associated apartments each time you save house or street.

Now you can search using full `Apartment#text`

```
Account.
  joins(:apartment).
  where('apartment.cached_text' => text)
```

or a substring of it

```
Account.
  joins(:apartment).
  where("apartment.cached_text LIKE '%?%'", text)
```

Comment: it's wrong! I haven't this field separately and i must filter by defined string.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand.  What are "this field" and "defined string" you refer to?  I'll write out the first option I refer to in my answer in case it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
your_result = Account.includes(:apartment, :apartment => :house, :apartment => {:house => :street}).where(:apartment => {:number => ...}).where(:house => {:number => ...}).where(:street => {:name => ...})
```